# Kotlin syntactic sugar: make var all private in constructor

Tags: constructor, kotlin, private

I'm new to kotlin and astonished by all the useful syntactic sugars and features it contains.

But whenever I declare a constructor, I have to make all my fields private independantly.

```
class Result(private val startTime: String?, private val stopTime: String?, 
             private val niveau: Int, private val contraction: String?,
             private val VPcount: Int, private val VNcount: Int, 
             private val FPcount: Int, private val FNcount: Int) {...}
```

Is there any way I could write something like this ?

```
class Result(private {val startTime: String?, val stopTime: String?, 
             val niveau: Int, val contraction: String?,
             val VPcount: Int, val VNcount: Int, 
             val FPcount: Int, val FNcount: Int}) {...}
```

I couldn't find anything about this in [the doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this currently. The default visibility is public, and you can only change it on a per-property basis.

Perhaps your class could implement an interface that doesn't expose all these properties, and you could pass instances of it to client code as that type - although I don't know your exact situation and requirements.

Comment: That's what I thought, but you can never be sure if it doesn't exist or if you missed it. Thanks